# How can I set players to different teams?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

After adding red and blue teams to a scoreboard with death counters, how can I set players to certain teams? Like with pressure plates. Like if one player steps on this pressure plate, then they are added to the red team, and if another player steps on a **different** pressure plate, then they get added to the blue team. 

How do I do the command block(s) for that?

Comment: Simple. Do /team join Red and /team join Blue. If you join a team but you were already on a team, you will leave the first team to join the second.

Comment: and why did I get 2 dislikes 

Comment: idk, wasn't me.

Answer (score 1):

If you want them to put the command, have them say "/team join red". If they step on a pressure plate, put a command block under the block the plate is on and have the command /execute at @p run team join red or /execute at @p run team join blue. dissecting this...

execute: execute a command with special parameters

at: execute at an entity

@p: the nearest person

run: run a command

team: the teams command

join: join a team

red: the name of the team

as SpiceWeasel said...

> If you join a team but you were already on a team, you will leave the first team to join the second.

so, this method should allow you to keep all your teams' players in a row. GLHF

Comment: Ok thanks! Also, how do I add a scoreboard, which shows both teams and their number of deaths in total? Please give detailed commands I need, thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Use `/team add <team name>` then `/team join <player name>`.

You can color teams by using `/team modify <team name> color <color>`

Comment: I though it would show as I typed, guess it doen't matter if you start a new line. :P